# Como acesso a webcam por meio do PHP ou JAVASCRIPT?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou a construir um sistema para cadastro, e existe uma necessidade de se ter uma fotografia do usuário, e a dúvida é como ter acesso a WEB CAM por meio de um script PHP ou JAVASCRIPT, ou mesmo em HTML para poder capturar a imagem e posteriormente fazer o Upload!
Alguém tem uma ideia por favor?

Answer (score -1):

Voce pode tentar utilizar este framework em javascript.

https://webrtc.org/

Tambem existe um tutorial bem legal bem detalhado no site da MDN com alguns exemplos pra comecar a fazer seus testes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos